# SvelteKit with Nginx returns response error 500

Tags: nginx, sveltekit

Im trying to build `SvelteKit` project and host it on a server with `nginx`, using `@sveltejs/adapter-static`. The app works fine when developing locally but when build it and upload it im getting `500 JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` for some of the routes.

The routes in problem are sourcing their data from a `json` file (part of the project).

My folder structure is:

```
src/
├── data/
│   └── my_data.json
└── routes/
    ├── api/
    │   └── something.json.js
    └── area/
        └── [method].svelte
```

`something.json.js`

```js
import * as siteData from "../data/my_data.json";

export async function GET({ url }) {
  const param = url.searchParams.get("method");

  const body = siteData[param];

  return {
    body
  }
})
```

`[method].svelte`

```js
<script context="module">
    export const load = async ({ params, fetch }) => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/something.json?method=${params.method}`);
        const posts = await response.json();

        return {
            props: {
                posts
            }
        };
    };
</script>

<script>
  export let posts;
</script>

<div>
  <!-- do something with "data" here -->
</div>
```

`svelte.config.js`

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

`nginx.conf`

```js
http {
   server {
      listen 80;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

      location / {
         root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
          
         try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html /index.html;
      }
   }
}
```

With this setup:

- `http://localhost:3000/area/method1` displays all ok
- `http://my-server.com/area/method1` displays:

  [image: error]

My (wild) guesses:

- this will never work because there is no actual back-end to handle the endpoint code
- `nginx` misconfiguration when trying to call/serve `/api/something.json`

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar problem (but using `@sveltejs/adapter-node`)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Ended loading the json into the app instead fetching it on runtime.

Comment: Ok, thx, I guess I will do that too then